# Using /usr/bin/file to determine file type?

Tags: php, linux, file, file-upload, identification

I'm planning to use this system program  /usr/bin/file  to determine uploaded file content type and then act accordingly.

Is this a good idea or are there things I should watch out for? (Or use something altogether different)

Comment: Need more context ... the tag 'file-upload' implies you're dealing with uploaded files, in which case the file type should be in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has the [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension, which uses the same mechanism but is native to PHP.

Answer (score 3):

[`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/mime_content_type) and [`finfo_file`](http://php.net/finfo_file) are the preferred methods for determining a mime type (either one is often enabled in most php distributions). They use the same magic.mime database as the external tool, which is why I would use that as fallback only.

Using the external tool also requires extracting the mime type from the output, so it's somewhat involving code:

```
$type = exec("/usr/bin/file -iL " .escapeshellcmd($fn). " 2>/dev/null");
if ($type = trim(strtok(substr(strrchr($type, ":"), 1), ";"))) {
    return $type;
}
```

If your question is about reliability: yes, that's a good approach. Determining the file type by magic bytes is quite reliable on all current Linux/U*ix servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a PECL extension (or are using php >= 5.3), I would recommend that you use the [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension.

If not, the [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function will do, but please note that it is now deprecated (in favor or fileinfo)

Comment: Just a small heads-up, since PHP 5.3, Fileinfo is included by default.

Comment: Thanks, edited my answer. Now I just wish some legacy code could just disappear overnight so I could use 5.3 ...